# Foundation Zurb media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to switch places of these two columns large-8 and large-4, I want the text to be under the image when the page is being viewed on small screen.

[image]

the columns structure is like this

```
div id="roofing">
            <div class="large-8 columns">
                <h3>Roofing</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Vitae tempora quia voluptas iure iste quas libero esse maiores dolore illo magni quo magnam voluptatem,
                        ea suscipit, quaerat omnis delectus dolorem!
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> -->
                <img src="imgs/roofing.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Media Query (40em)

```
#roofing{
        .large-8{
            // width: 33.33333%;
            float: left;
            background: red;
        }
        .large-4{
            // width: 66.66667%;
            float: right;
        }
    }
```

I thought changing its float will work but unfortunately it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need css for that just foundation's predefined classes (combined) `small` *live* [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6u3acsae/6/) and alternate `large-push` and `large-pull` numbers

change you markup to this [full page DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6u3acsae/6/embedded/result/)

```
<div id="roofing" class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-push-8 small-12 columns">
        <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> -->
        <img src="imgs/roofing.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 large-pull-4 small-12 columns">
        <h3>Roofing</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Vitae tempora quia voluptas iure iste quas libero esse maiores dolore illo magni quo magnam voluptatem,
            ea suscipit, quaerat omnis delectus dolorem!
        </p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry should have edited mine, I've found this solution now I remembered that there's a order columns in their doc. But will give it a check :).